# Git command to undo the commit for a single file when there is only one commit?

Tags: git

One of my team member made changes to the eclipse `.project` file and commited and it shows as below.

```
Javanoob@DELL:~/workspace/Project$ git log -- .project
commit 1b8d8529b334343543rfefcfsdwerwedwdssadd5
Author: Some Developer <some_developer@mail.com>
Date:   Tue Dec 29 10:37:10 2015 -0500

    Committed.
```

I want to restore this file to the old state it was before this particular commit.

After googling I found that I can use `git checkout abcde file/to/restore` but I am not sure what to give in place of `abcde` in this command as the git log shows only one commit as the history for this file.

**EDIT** This particular file has only one commit and no more commits before this one.

Comment: `abcde` should be substituted with the SHA of the commit you want to undo (`1b8d8529b334343543rfefcfsdwerwedwdssadd5` in this case). You can also just use the first several characters of the SHA, enough to make it unambiguous.

Comment: The problem is that this file has only one commit so I am confused on how to go back to the state of the file before this commit.

Comment: So just `git rm` the file and commit that change.

Comment: ...and add the file to `.gitignore` file so that no one checks it in by accident the next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's only one commit, and it's your co-worker's, then that file wasn't checked in before your co-worker committed it.  Git has no previous version.  Git cannot restore it to the state it was in before that particular commit because, as far as Git is concerned, the previous state is "empty".

The best you can do is check your own backups of that directory.

Comment: Looks like you are correct because when I tried David's solution it says error pathspec.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you *never* want your `.project` file committed, but you *do* want it locally:

1. `git rm --cached path/to/file` will stage the file for removal but keep it on disk
2. Create or edit your `.gitignore` file to include `*.project`.
3. `git add .gitignore` to stage the ignore file
4. `git commit -m "backed out project"` to remove the .project file and add the ignore file

Comment: Is there any option locally so that even if somebody makes changes to the `.project` file and when I use the `git pull` command it does not overwrite my .project file?

Comment: The ignore file should stop anyone else checking in their project file, so there shouldn't be anything to overwrite yours. That is, of course, unless they choose to change the ignore file too. If you're worried about losing your own changes to your .project file then that's a clue that it either needs backing up or a copy checking it at some other path.

Comment: That means there is no way to tell Git to stop overwriting a particular file with commits from others?

Comment: Matthew, I will post this as a new question. Thanks for your time.